# Trying to open an activity from a navigation drawer item

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make the "sign out" item take me back to the Login window. I did a lot of searching and watching videos but nothing worked for me.

Here's my built-in navigation drawer code.
The code I typed starts from line 46 to line 56, most codes are just built-in.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityHomepageBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarHomepage.toolbar);
    binding.appBarHomepage.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }

    });



    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id=menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_Sign_out){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_dashboard, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_orders, R.id.nav_recent_orders,
            R.id.nav_pending_deliveries, R.id.nav_cancelled_orders, R.id.nav_settings)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_homepage);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homepage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_homepage);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();


}
```

}

Login.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignUp);

    textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Homepage.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}
```

}

It doesn't have an error but it doesn't work.

Here's the activity_main_drawer.xml where I put the items.

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/menu_top"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_dashboard_24"
        android:title="@string/dashboard">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:title="@string/profile" >
    </item>
</group>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_orders"
    android:title="@string/orders" >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_menu_orders"
            android:title="@string/Orders"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_orders" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_recent_orders"
            android:title="@string/recent_orders"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_recent" />
    </menu>
</item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_deliveries"
        android:title="@string/deliveries" >
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_pending_deliveries"
                android:title="@string/pending_deliveries"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_pending_deliveries"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_recent_deliveries"
                android:title="@string/recent_deliveries"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_recent" />
        </menu>

    </item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_cancelled_orders"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_cancel_24"
    android:title="@string/cancelled_orders" >
    </item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
    android:title="@string/settings" >

</item>

<group
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu_bottom"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_Sign_out"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sign_out"
        android:title="@string/sign_out">
    </item>
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this -**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         binding = ActivityHomepageBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarHomepage.toolbar);
    binding.appBarHomepage.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }

    });



    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


 // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_dashboard, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_orders, R.id.nav_recent_orders,
            R.id.nav_pending_deliveries, R.id.nav_cancelled_orders, R.id.nav_settings)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_homepage);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

 }

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homepage, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_homepage);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();


}

 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

       int id=menuItem.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.nav_Sign_out){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Homepage.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I tried your comment but it still doesn't work.

Comment: please check this nav_Sign_out in your menu file. is proper or not

Comment: I added the activity_main_drawer.xml please look at it. Thank you